# Access server's camera with pure PHP

Tags: php, camera

I'm trying to setup a website in which the user will have access to the server's camera. It will be as simple as that.

It is just a web camera plugged into an USB port. The website consists of a single page that has only a single button on it, and a div in which the picture will get displayed. The picture will be displayed on the moment I click the button. I know I can access the client's camera trough JavaScript. But here I'm trying to make some website visitor to access the server's camera, **the server from which the website is hosted trough XAMPP on a Windows OS**.

My project is bigger than what I described but I described this in a short way because this is the only thing I'm stuck with.

**How can I access my PC's hardware trough PHP? How to make screenshot only using PHP. Thats my only question.** Thanks for your time.

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2492049/can-i-control-hardware-via-php-language

Comment: How does your camera provide the image? For example some of them provide a mini HTTP server that will serve the current image as a JPEG file - if yours does, then just use CURL or even perhaps `file_get_contents()` to get the current image from the camera, then serve it to the user.

Comment: "You might want to look into php exec. PHP doesn't allow Direct access to Hardware through the API, you need to call sub-programs to do that."

Understood. I guess now i need to make a separate program to make/rename and place the screenshots in the proper directory. Thanks for the answers guys. Wish me less headblowing durring those days :D